# julia replace singlequote Dataframe replaces with \"

Tags: json, dataframe, csv, replace, julia

I tried to replace in my csv file the singlequotes with double quote to parse into json. When I tried the code below every single quot gets replaces with \" instead of " how can i prevent this. I also tried out the line which i commented out resulted in the same output.

Thanks in advance

```
using Pipe
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Statistics

using Dates
using Plots
using JSON

df = DataFrame(CSV.File("movies_metadata.csv"))
select!(df, Not([:video, :poster_path, :overview, :id, :imdb_id, :homepage, :original_title, :adult]))
dropmissing!(df, :status)
filter!(:status => ==("Released"), df)


df.genres = replace(df.genres, "'" => "\"")



#s = Char(34)

#df = df.replace({'\'': '"'}, regex=True)

#df.genres = replace.(df.genres, "'" => s)
#df = df.str.replace(r"[\"]", r"'")
#df.genres = replace.(df.genres, "\"" => "" )

#spacex_dict = JSON.parse(df.genres)


#replace!(df.genres, r"'$" => "\"")
```

Comment: Do you need the quotes at all in your use case? JSON may want to handle any needed quotes itself.

Comment: The csv data got the quote marks and i can't parse into the json without them changed

Comment: Changed, or deleted?

Comment: Changed into Double quots

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping to replace the column entries:

```
df.genres = map(s -> replace(s, "'" => "\""), df.genres)
```

Note the backslash char in the replace is a single backslash.

This allows a parse:

```
@show JSON.parse(df.genres[1])
3-element Vector{Any}:
 Dict{String, Any}("name" => "Animation", "id" => 16)
 Dict{String, Any}("name" => "Comedy", "id" => 35)
 Dict{String, Any}("name" => "Family", "id" => 10751)
```